# Angular js route not working with external controller files

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jsp, ngroute

i am trying to add ngroute to my applications. i am using external controller files. but route it not working. my external controller file is name-ct.jsp.

```
<ul>
 <li class="treeview">
     <a href="#name-details">
     </a>
     </li>
```

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

```
// configure our routes
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/name-details', {
            templateUrl : 'name-details.jsp',
            controller  : 'myCtrl',

        });
});
```